# SQLl create table /w select statements and defined date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to track down new id numbers over time for at least the past twelve months. Note, the data is such that once id numbers are in, they stick around for at least 3-5 years. And I just literally run this thing once a month. These are the specs, Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production.

So far I'm wondering if I can use more dynamic date ranges and run this whole thing on a timer, or if this is the best way to write something. I've just picked up sql mostly through Googling and looking at sample queries that others have graciously shared. I also do not know how to write PL/SQL right now either but am willing to learn.

```
create table New_ids_calendar_year_20xx
as
select b.id_num, (bunch of other fields)
from (select * from source_table where date = last_day(date_add(sysdate,-11))a,  (select * from source_table where date = last_day(date_add(sysdate,-10))b where a.id_num (+) = b.id_num

union all
```

*repeats this same select statement /w union all until:

```
last_day(date_add(sysdate,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle there is no built-in function date_add, maybe you have some which you created, anyway for adding and substracting dates 
I used simple sysdate+number. Also I am not quite sure about logic behind your whole query. And for field names - better avoid 
[reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) like `date` in column names, so I used 
`tdate` here.

This query does what your unioned query did for last 30 days. For other periods change `30` to something other. 
The whole solution is based on the [hierarchical](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#SQLRF52315) 
subquery `connect by`  which gives simple list of numbers 0..29.

```
select b.id_num, b.field1 field1_b, a.field1 field1_a  --..., (bunch of other fields) 
  from (select level - 1 lvl from dual connect by level <= 30) l
    join source_table b 
      on b.tdate = last_day(trunc(sysdate) - l.lvl - 1) 
    left join source_table a 
      on a.id_num = b.id_num and a.tdate = last_day(trunc(sysdate) - l.lvl)
  order by lvl desc
```

For date column you may want to use `trunc(tdate)` if you store time also, but this way your index on date field will not work if one exists.
In this case change date condition to something like `x-1 <= date and date < x`.